# How to change standard schematic for ambient light sensor TSL25911FN

Tags: schematic

I am implementing ambient light sensor TSL25911FN into my design schema.

[A]

[image]

[image]

VCC = +3.3V, SDA_SC and SCL_SC use standar +3.3V logic.

Here is standard implementation of such sensor by producers like Adafruit, Waveshare with this mixed logic (5/3.3V)

[B]

[image]

VCC = +5V or +3.3V, SDA and SCL use same logic 5/3.3V.

In my case I use only 3.3V logic. Standard schema "stabilize" voltage from +3.3V to +3.3V and shift level logic by NDC7002N shift 3.3V to 3.3V.

From my point of view there is not necessary to use shift level logic and stabilization of voltage IC's.

Schema [B] communicate with my GPIO ports (3.3V logic) at 100 or 400 kHz I2C frequency.

```
comet@mangopi:~/ecomet_i2c_raspberry_tools$ i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:                         -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 29 -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

But origin implementation [A] (without additional IC's) did not respond to I2C requests. Shortly it not works.

Could you give me advice any possible reason why it works only in case of [B] schema? I just want to mention that othter I2C chips at schema [A] are connected in serial is working. So there is no issue with some length of cable or some noise at line.

Comment: Schema [A] contains also pull-up resistor 2k2, low pass filter, Ferrite Beads

Comment: Marian Minar - Re: "*Schema [A] contains also pull-up resistor 2k2*" That makes my answer partially or completely obsolete, depending what was omitted (which is fine, I half-expected that your question was missing important details). However this just shows that it is **very** important for you to add the information I mentioned: Please ASAP [edit] your question and add *all* relevant details, symptoms, observations, troubleshooting results and *full* schematics. Otherwise other site members will also waste their time, due to details that are currently missing in the question. Thanks.

Comment: At this moment I did not see some different symptoms. SCL and SDA signals seams to be same. I hope that there is not problem with soldering. (TSL chips is looking like BGA chip, pins are from bottom of it)

Comment: Marian Minar - Hi, I see that you have changed the question to add a new part to schematic A. However you have not added the full schematics, so I won't be able to continue on this. I will just recommend that you use an oscilloscope (not a logic analyser) to view relevant signal levels and quality e.g. rise/fall times. Also, your new schematic A still does not show the pull-up on that IC's INT pin which, according to its [datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/588/TSL2591_DS000338_6_00-1623895.pdf) is needed, if used. This is another reason why I said that *full* schematics are needed!

Comment: In my schema I did not pull INT pin with resistor and now is open (not connected).  I will check it by oscilloscope again and write details after testing. I did not check  rise/fall times that's right.